# ignoring characters from string javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using the themoviedb API and am trying to append movie posters to a web page through JSON data that they make available.

The code I have is:

`<div id="poster"></div>`

and the JS/jQuery code looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( "#form" ).submit(function() {
  ( result = $("input:first" ).val());
  console.log(result)
  // var result = 122;
  $.ajax({
     url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + result + "?api_key=###",
     dataType:"jsonp"
     }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        $( "#poster" ).empty();
     $( "#poster" ).prepend('<img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + data.poster_path  />');
  });
```

});
});

The poster path is provided by the API and a full path would look like this

http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/1l3WpoF7TX9pOprX4XepCXjQXUV.jpg

The final part is the poster path. The difficulty I am having is that I want to add the poster path at the end, however as the img tags need to be inside two speech marks i.e(' ') the poster path cannot be accessed.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Thank you, Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, just missing a couple quotes to concatenate:

```
$( "#poster" ).prepend('<img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"' + data.poster_path + '" />');
```